# Remove package ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-ec2, vagrant, ansible

I've an EC2 instance create using Vagrant and provisioned with Ansible.

I've this task that install 2 package using `apt`.

```
---
- name: Install GIT & TIG
  action: apt pkg={{ item }} state=installed
  with_items:
    - git
    - tig
```

I want now delete/remove `tig` from my instance. I've removed it from my playbook and I've run `vagrant provision` but the package is still there.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ansible cannot automatically remove packages when you remove them from you playbook. Ansible is *stateless*. This means it will not keep track of what it does and therefore does not know what it did in recent runs or if your playbook/role has been modified. Ansible will only do what you explicitly describe in the playbook/role. So you have to write a task to remove it.

You can easily do this with the apt module.

```yaml
- name: Remove TIG
  apt:
    pkg: tig
    state: absent
  become: true
```

Answer (score 5):

Removing the package from playbook will ensure that package is not installed on a newly provisioned machine, but the package will not be removed if that is already installed on a provisioned machine. If possible, you can destroy the machine using `vagrant destroy` and create/provision a new one.

If it is not possible to destroy the machine and provision a new one then you can add an ansible task to remove the installed package. Using `absent` as the state will remove the package.

```
- name: Remove TIG
  action: apt pkg=tig state=absent
```

Answer (score 2):

Sudo is now deprecated and no longer recommended. Use become instead.

```
- name: Remove TIG
  apt:
    pkg: tig
    state: absent
  become: yes
```